# Extracting string from a vector without using a loop

Tags: r

I have a character vector from which I want to extract some strings. I can achieve it by using a loop but was wondering if same can be done without using one. I have included an example vector with the code that I have.

```
egVec = c("a - (2),bewc", "c,d,e","efd, ejw, qdn", "we3, asw - 23")
```

I want to extract the first element of each vector such that the required output will be:

```
Vec1
  [1] "a - (2)" "c" "efd" "we3"
```

My code which uses a for loop:

```
Vec1 = as.character(0)
for (i in 1:length(egVec)){
  SplitVec = unlist(strsplit(egVec[i], ","))
  Vec1[i] = SplitVec[1]
}
```

Comment: @hrbrmstr: is this really a FAQ? If so, is this question the best candidate for the canonical question?

Comment: As I said below. Folk are free to remove the tag. It's my opine. It's not any less meaningful than the rest of your opines, but I'm not arguing abt it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
library(purrr)
library(stringi)

egVec <- c("a - (2),bewc", "c,d,e","efd, ejw, qdn", "we3, asw - 23")

strsplit(egVec, ",") %>%
  vapply(`[`, character(1), 1)                     # type-safe base R
## [1] "a - (2)" "c"       "efd"     "we3"

strsplit(egVec, ",") %>%
  sapply(`[`, 1)                                   # non-type-safe base R
## [1] "a - (2)" "c"       "efd"     "we3"

strsplit(egVec, ",") %>%
  map_chr(1)                                       # type-safe tidyvere
## [1] "a - (2)" "c"       "efd"     "we3"

stri_split_fixed(egVec, ",", 2, simplify=TRUE)[,1] # stringi one-liner splitting strings
## [1] "a - (2)" "c"       "efd"     "we3"

gsub(",.*$", "", egVec)                            # base R one-liner string replacing
## [1] "a - (2)" "c"       "efd"     "we3"

stri_replace_first_regex(egVec, ",.*$", "")        # stringi one-liner string replacing
## [1] "a - (2)" "c"       "efd"     "we3"
```

Benchmark:

```
library(microbenchmark)
library(ggplot2)

microbenchmark(
  vapply=strsplit(egVec, ",") %>% vapply(`[`, character(1), 1),
  sapply=strsplit(egVec, ",") %>% sapply(`[`, 1),
  map_chr=strsplit(egVec, ",") %>% map_chr(1),
  stri_split=stri_split_fixed(egVec, ",", 2, simplify=TRUE)[,1] ,
  gsub=gsub(",.*$", "", egVec),
  stri_replace=stri_replace_first_regex(egVec, ",.*$", "")
) -> mb

mb
## Unit: microseconds
##          expr     min       lq      mean   median       uq      max neval cld
##        vapply 109.657 140.6025 169.51454 159.9715 181.4645 1102.825   100   b
##        sapply 125.206 147.8225 176.49470 172.4420 196.8730  396.046   100   b
##       map_chr 123.767 145.7385 179.12090 177.9535 198.2710  325.098   100   b
##    stri_split   6.626  12.7120  15.60843  14.6755  17.6315   68.299   100  a 
##          gsub  13.912  20.5335  24.99184  23.8180  28.1800   45.563   100  a 
##  stri_replace  17.532  25.8590  30.81416  28.9465  31.0715  170.869   100  a

autoplot(mb)
```

[image]

(Not an optimal test harness for the benchmark but I figured `stri_split…` wld come out on top).

I'm also so used to using `gsub()` that I forgot to just use `sub()`. It has almost identical benchmarks to `gsub()` though. However, it's fairer to use `sub()` for the comparison to `stri_replace_first_regex()`.

Comment: My bad. muscle memory from `stri_`. Remove the tag if you don't like it. I'm not going to get into another pedantic war with you. It's not worth my time/energy.

Comment: Or you could have made the edits rather than rant. That's one big reason it's not worth the effort to respond.